# Basic python calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I have a young friend of mine who is starting to learn Python in school and asked me to give him a little assignment. I am in no way a teacher nor a Python expert, but I accepted.

At first I thought it would be fun to start with a bit of parsing for the operation's input, like:

```
Enter your operation : 3+3
```

But it seemed a bit overwhelming for him so we agreed to separate it in three parts (first number, operand and second number).

I did a little correction but I find it clumsy and the point of the exercise is to show him some good practices.

So here is my code:

```py
calculate = True
while calculate:
    try:
        number1 = float(input("Enter the first number : "))
    except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect value")
            exit()
    symbol = input("Enter the operation symbol (+,-,/,*,%) : ")
    try:
        number2 = float(input("Enter the second number : "))
    except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect value")
            exit()
    operande = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "%"]
    resSentence = "Result of operation \"{} {} {}\" is :".format(number1, symbol, number2)
    if symbol not in operande:
        print("Incorrect symbol")
    elif symbol == "+":
        print(resSentence, number1 + number2)
    elif symbol == "-":
        print(resSentence, number1 - number2)
    elif symbol == "*":
        print(resSentence, number1 * number2)
    elif symbol == "/":
        print(resSentence, number1 / number2)
    elif symbol == "%":
        print(resSentence, number1 % number2)
    restart = input("Do you want to do another calcul (Y/n) ? ")
    while restart.lower() != "y" and restart.lower() != "n":
        print(restart.lower(), restart.lower(), restart.lower()=="n")
        restart = input("Please, enter \"y\" to continue or \"n\" to exit the program : ")
    if restart.lower() == "n":
        calculate = False
```

I would have wanted to do a loop when `number1` or `number2` is not a valid `float` until the user enter a valid value, but I did not found a clean way to do it. I would gladly accept advices about this (even though I know this is not a question for this Stack Exchange, a good Pythonic way for doing this would be cool :) ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use more functions

You have a function `calculate()`, but if you see it does much more than just calculate, this makes your code look unreasonably clunky. But there is a very simply solution, use more functions. What if your main-loop could look like

```py
while True:
    number1,number2,operand = take_input()
    result = calculate(number1,number2,operand)
    print(f"Answer : {numebr1} {operand} {number2} = {result}")
    if input("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ").lower() == 'n':
        break
```

This makes it easier to maintain your program.

## `continue` when there is an error

```py
try:
    number1 = float(input("Enter the first number : "))
except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect value")
        exit()
```

Ask yourself, why would a program terminate if the user enters invalid input? **Give him a another chance xD**

## Maintain consistent indentation

```py
try:
    number2 = float(input("Enter the second number : "))
except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect value")
            exit()
```

Try to maintain consistent indentation, since you have used `4` spaces earlier, there is no good reason to use `8` later, it might just confuse people who read the code later.

## Code logic 1

Let's consider this sample input

```
Enter the first number : 1
Enter the operation symbol (+,-,/,*,%) : I like python
Enter the second number : 2
Incorrect symbol
```

Clearly, the `symbol` is wrong. Why did I have to enter the second number, just to find out I made a mistake while entering the `symbol`? It should've told me right away that my symbol was incorrect, so I could've corrected it.

Just move the `if symbol not in operands` statement so it sits right next to the input.

## `eval`

[**Eval in Python**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_eval.asp#:%7E:text=The%20eval()%20function%20evaluates,statement%2C%20it%20will%20be%20executed.)

This would be the biggest improvement in your program, since it converts about 10-15 lines of code, into one.

> The `eval()` function evaluates the specified expression, if the
> expression is a legal Python statement, it will be executed.

That sounds familiar, aren't we basically evaluating simple expressions?

Using `eval`, your calculation part would look like

```py
result = eval(f"{number1}{operand}{number2}")
```

Example, `number1 = 5,number2 = 10, operand = '+'`

This is what is basically happening

```py
result = eval("5+10")
```

## Final

Here is the code with the improvements

```py
def take_input():
    err_msg = "Invalid input"
    operands = ['+','-','*','/','%']
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Enter number 1: "))
    except Exception:
        print(err_msg)
        return take_input()
    try:
        num2 = float(input("Enter number 2: "))
    except Exception:
        print(err_msg)
        return take_input()

    print("Operands: " + ', '.join(x for x in operands))
    try:
        operand = input("Enter operand: ")
    except Exception:
        print(err_msg)
        return take_input()

    if operand not in operands:
        print(err_msg)
        return take_input()

    return num1,num2,operand

def calculate(num1,num2,operand):
    return eval(f"{num1}{operand}{num2}")


def mainloop():
    while True:
        num1,num2,operand = take_input()
        result = calculate(num1,num2,operand)
        print(f"Answer: {result}")
        if input("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ").lower() == 'n':
            break

mainloop()
```

Comment: I really like the improvements you proposed and how you explained them to me :) As a side question do you think this would be understandable to my young friend (14 y/o) who just started python and only saw `if` statement in class (he is motivated though since he himself came to me to learn more about coding and so far he seems to really enjoy it). I guess the harder will be to not give him the code but to let him do some search and do trial and error by himself ^^. I will wait untill tonight (I am in France) before accepting an answer but so far, I will accept yours :)

Comment: Well I'll do my best to explain him as clearly as possible and to let him search by himself :) Wow I would really not have guessed, you have a bright future ahead of you

Comment: @L.Faros There are plenty of resources to learn python online.  [This](https://programmingwithmosh.com/python/new-python-tutorial/) one was extremely useful to me

Comment: @L.Faros the final code could be thought of as `If` statements. Basically, all `Try/Except` is doing is saying (using the first one as an example) "If setting `num1` to a float results in a Value error, print the error message and re-run `take_input`. If there is no error setting `num1` to a float, then do that and continue to the next line after `except`".

Comment: Something I noticed, if the users second input results in an error, they have to restart and put in number 1 again. Perhaps that's by design and is intended, but one alternate would be to just ask for the second number again (via whatever method you like).  Same with operand. (Though this is a simple program so it's probably overkill. Just something for OP to consider trying)

Comment: My mistake; there is validation being done - it's just doing it in a pretty bad way. 1. You recurse instead of loop. You really shouldn't recurse. 2. Your code doesn't even do what you intended - retries don't return any values; you discard the return values. That aside, `eval` still isn't the right tool, here; given that your operators are well-constrained and well-understood you should not need to force the interpreter to parse anything.

Comment: It's not a performance problem. It's just literally the wrong thing to do, and you'll blow your stack if the user enters enough bad data. Subsequent runs of the function don't depend on previous runs of the function; this is not a proper application of recursion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115350/discussion-between-reinderien-and-aryan-parekh).

Comment: Although using _eval_ is fine in such educational cases, I’d like to add that using _eval_ without checking/restricting the string that is eval’ed is a very serious security concern.

Comment: @agtoever He's right actually, it can be dangerous but it works in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternative to your code, it is a bit more complex but it is also more readable. I did manage to do the loop thing but it is kind of hard to follow. Sorry.

```py
running = True
# Break Things up into functions each function does one single thing

def calculate(inputOne, operand, inputTwo):
    """
    Calculates inputOne operand and inputTwo
    """

    if operand == "+":
        return inputOne + inputTwo
    elif operand == "-":
        return inputOne - inputTwo
    elif operand == "*":
        return inputOne * inputTwo
    elif operand == "/":
        return inputOne / inputTwo
    elif operand == "%":
        return inputOne % inputTwo

def askInput():
    """
    Asks for a number until a number is given checks if each one is valid
    """

    isValid = [False, False, False] # none of the numbers are validated yet
    number1, symbol, number2 = ["", "", ""]
    
    # Here is a good implementation of the loop, it is kind of complex though
    while True:
        try:
            if not isValid[0]: # Asks for number1 if it is not valid
                number1 = int(input("Enter the first number : "))
                isValid[0] = True

            if not isValid[1]: # This is added functionality because there was a loophole in your program
                symbol = input("Enter the operation symbol (+,-,/,*,%) : ") # use tuples whenever possible
                supportedOperands = ("+", "-", "/", "*", "%")

                if symbol not in supportedOperands:
                    raise ValueError

                isValid[1] = True

            if not isValid[2]: # Asks for number2 if it is not valid
                number2 = int(input("Enter the second number : "))
                isValid[2] = True
            break
        
        except ValueError:
            continue # this just restarts the whole thing
    
    return number1, symbol, number2



def continueApp():
    """
    Checks if the input to restart is valid
    """
    restart = input("Do You want to do another calculation (Y/n) ? ").lower()

    while True:
        if restart == "y":
            return True
        elif restart == "n":
            return False
        else:
            restart = input("Please, enter \"y\" to continue or \"n\" to exit the program : ").lower()

while running:

    numberOne, operand, numberTwo = askInput()
    answer = calculate(numberOne, operand, numberTwo)
    resSentence = f"Result of operation {numberOne} {operand} {numberTwo} is : {answer}"
    print(resSentence)

    if continueApp():
        pass
    else:
        running = False
exit()
```

## Tips:

- ### Break Things Up into functions:

Functions are just containers for code that can be executed, functions *MUST* do *ONE* and only *ONE* thing more on functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

- ### Please Try to comment on your code, it makes it easier to read and edit.

This function

```
def calc():
    x = 1
    y = 12
    return (((x+y)/x)**y)+(3*x+4*y) # Please don't write like this in any case
```

would be much better with an explanation or what is going on

```
def calc():
    """
    Accepts: Nothing
    Does: Adds X and Y, then divides it by X to the power of Y
          then it adds  it to X multiplied by three and 4 multiplied by Y
    Returns: integer (the result of Does) ^^^^^
    """
    x = 1
    y = 12
    return ((x+y)/x**y)+(3*x+4*y) # Again, please don't write code like this
```

- ### Use f strings (this requires python 3.6 and above)

f strings are used like this

```
value = "12"
print(f"Number {value} is an example of an f string") 

# Versus

print("Number {} is an example of an f string".format(value))
```

- ### Try to space out your code

Trust me, this makes your code easier to read and understand.

```
def calc():
    """
    Accepts: Nothing
    Does: Adds X and Y, then divides it by X to the power of Y
          then it adds  it to X multiplied by three and 4 multiplied by Y
    Returns: integer (the result of Does) ^^^^^
    """
    x = 1
    y = 12
    ans = (x + y) / (x ** y)
    ans += (3 * x) + (4 * y) # just adds ans to the right side of the operator
    return ans
```

Comment: The `operand` could be the key of a dictionary, that leads to \$O(1)\$ search time.

Comment: Well I tried to avoid functions since he is a new learner and the exercise should be more oriented about basics programming skills (conditions, loop...) but tyvm

Comment: Though I like your implementation, I would like to go step by step and avoid using functions since he is young and already have difficulties following a simple script

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be focused on code review but rather to offer an alternative solution. Would you mind explaining (edit your answer) how is this any better from the OP's code? What did you improve?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I will fix that.